# is it possible to auth against a facebook place in order to get its feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website where we'd like to access the facebook content of one of our locations which has a facebook places page. If it was Staples Center, this page: https://www.facebook.com/staplescenter?ref=mf. Is this possible? Would I need to be auth'd for this info?

I have seen this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

but don't really see any place where it discusses places that you can access.

Answer (score 0):

A place is a page, and how to access the page feed is described at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/feed#readperms

Quote:

> **Permissions**
>
> - An access token is required to view publicly shared posts.
> - A user access token is required to retrieve posts visible to that person.
> - A page access token is required to retrieve any other posts.
> - A user access token with ads_management permission or a page access token is > * required for `/{page-id}/promotable_posts`.

If you're only interested in pages you're an administrator of, then I'd suggest you use a page access token, as outlined at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens